# Error in cURL : Could not resolve host: domain

Tags: ubuntu, curl, php-curl

I found articles with the same issue but the answers didn't fix my problem, so I m trying to curl from and to the same Ubuntu server, but it returns: Error in cURL: Could not resolve host: [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

when i do: `wget www.domain.com`, i have : |127.0.0.1|:443... failed: Connection refused.

when I do: `telnet www.domain.com`, I have: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

I added to /etc/hosts the line: 127.0.0.1  domain.com

I have listed netstat on 443 : `netstat -tlpen | grep 443` but no 0.0.0.0:443 or 127.0.0.1:443 is in the list

When I curl the same domain from another server, it returns the wanted result.
Here is my Php curl code :

```
<?php 

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.fakedomain.co');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    if($data === false) {
        echo "Error in cURL : " . curl_error($curl);
    }
    else{
        echo $data;
    }
```

Comment: The issue is likely that `domain.com` is not the same domain as `www.domain.com`

Comment: If this is all a problem when running cURL in a terminal, it's not related to programming, but to networking issues

Comment: You need to have a (web)server running. If there is no server running you will get the `failed: Connection refused`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed my problem, Updated the /etc/hosts file like this :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       domain.com
Server IP       domain.com
```